# What is a type in Typescript for the Component class in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a small problem, but big frustration. To my custom module, I need to pass an array of components. So... To keep good habits, I want to describe it using Typescript. It looks something like this:

```
export interface ModalModuleConfig {
    title: string;
    z-index: number;
    entryComponents: Component[];
}
```

But `Component[]` isn't a proper type. It only works with `any[]`. But I don't want to cut corners using `any[]`. I prefer to use type created for the angular components. Something like `Component[]`, `ComponentDecorator[]` or `ComponentClass[]`. But none of them works. Can someone help me?

Comment: Component[] means array of component, all component inherits from component class

Comment: But why? Angular source code itself defines `entryComponents` as `any[]` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/metadata/ng_module.ts

Comment: Hi ! Component is not a type, it is a decorator. 
Infact a constant.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e4558908533d3ef3e3b741844a802fd7bdc8766/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L754

Comment: How about `ComponentRef` - will that work for you? https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef   - You have not mentioned what you do with `entryComponents` - are you passing Class of component or instance of components?

Comment: Guys, I tried all of your suggestion, but nothing works. @WandMaker I am passing Class of component, not the instance. So ComponentRef also doesn't work.
@AmitChigadani, I think you convinced me. If Anagular uses `any[]` it is possible that there isn't other way to describe the Component class type.